# Installing mysql on Yesod

Tags: mysql, haskell, functional-programming, cabal

I successfully created a Yesod app (using cabal-dev) and launching it.
but I have been trying to use mysql with yesod, but I always keep getting the following error message after running the command " cabal-dev install yesod-platform, cabal-dev install yesod-bin; cabal-dev install " :

```
 Installed yesod-1.2.2.1
 cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
 Youne-0.0.0 depends on pcre-light-0.4 which failed to install.
 mysql-0.1.1.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
 mysql-simple-0.2.2.4 depends on pcre-light-0.4 which failed to install.
 pcre-light-0.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
 persistent-mysql-1.2.1 depends on pcre-light-0.4 which failed to install.
```

I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a problem installing pcre-light, most likely due to missing system libraries. Try running just `cabal install pcre-light-0.4` and see if that output is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks Michael, running that command pointed out to me that the PCRE library was missing from my system. Wonderful, now I can proceed with Yesod. wonderful piece of software by the way.

Comment: I had similar issue, `pcre-light` failed to install because of absence in OS (OS X 10.9) PCRE executable. The solution was to install __PCRE__ via `brew install pcre`